# Upstart job to run Celery doesn't stop all the worker processes

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, celery, upstart

I have written an Upstart job to run celery in my Ubuntu server. Here's my configuration file called `celeryd.conf`

```
# celeryd - runs the celery daemon
#
# This task is run on startup to run the celery daemon

description "run celery daemon"

start on startup
expect fork
respawn

exec su - trakklr -c "/app/trakklr/src/trakklr celeryd --events --beat --loglevel=debug --settings=production"
```

When I execute `sudo service celeryd start`, the celeryd process starts just fine and all the x number of worker process start fine.

..but when I execute, `sudo service celeryd stop`, it stops most of the processes but a few processes are left hanging.

Why is this happening? I'm using Celery 2.5.3.

---

Here's an issue from the Github tracker.

https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure this out but it seemed to be an issue with my older celery version. I found this issue mentioned on their issue-tracker and I guess it points to the same issue:

https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/142

I upgraded my celery and django-celery to the 3.x.x versions and this issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I still use init.d to run celery so this may not apply. With that in mind, stopping the celery service sends the TERM signal to celery. This tells the workers not to accept new tasks but it does not terminate existing tasks. Therefore, depending on how long your tasks take to execute you may see tasks for some time after telling celery to stop. Eventually, they will all shut down unless you have some other problem.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue because I've inspected my task queue from RabbitMQ and there was nothing. I haven't been queuing tasks at all lately due to some other development work. I've upgraded to Celery 3.x.x and I'm hoping that that will resolve the issue. Have a look at my edit: I think this is a bug.